# adjective order

Tags: grammar, adjective-order

What is the correct order of adjectives in the following sentence?

> Comedians use offensive off-color jokes to make incredibly hysterical
> movies.

1. Offensive off-color jokes
2. Off-color offensive jokes

Which one is correct?

Comment: Either is correct, and both sound correct as well (which is not always the same thing).

Comment: Tell me, why do you use the AmE spelling of "color", as opposed to the BrE "colour"?